# Cron expression and spring kafkaTemplate compatibility

Tags: spring-boot, cron, spring-kafka

I schedule a job with cron expression in spring boot.
When I add maven spring-kafka dependency, my job doesn't start. This is the dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

On my class I use this annotations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "pushItems", name = "run", havingValue = "Y")
public class JobPushItems {

   @Autowired
   KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

   @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression.pushItems}")
   @Transactional()
   public void startExecutor() {
       ... spring code
   }
```

When, from pom.xml, I delete spring-kafka dependency (and kafkaTemplate autowired), the job starts fine. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The dependency you show has nothing to do with spring-kafka.

Post your complete project someplace (e.g. GitHub).

This works fine for me...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class So64098861Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So64098861Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    @Transactional
    public void sched() {
        System.out.println("here");
        this.template.send("topic1", "foo");
        this.template.send("topic1", "bar");
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("topic1").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}
```

```
$ kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic1 --from-beginning
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, but I solved my problem in this way. I removed the annotation @Transactional() under @Scheduled() and I call a private method:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression.pushItems}")
public void startExecutor() {
    startExecutorPrivate()
}

@Transactional()
private void startExecutorPrivate() {
    ... spring code
}
```